# evaluating a flux integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Question: "Region V, of unit volume, is bounded by the closed surface S. Given the vector field $\mathbf{F}=\langle 7x,2y,5z\rangle$, evaluate:

$$\int_S \mathbf{F}\cdot\mathbf{dS}$$

I guessed that by "unit volume" the question refers to a unit cube(?), but I can't get the right answer out and I'm really pretty stuck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: hint: use the divergence theorem. you don't need to know what the volume $V$ looks like; you just need to know its volume. (what is the divergence of your vector field?)

Comment: @symplectomorphic: From the comment above, I believe your hint should be turned into an "answer" (left as a hint of course).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: use the divergence theorem.(What is the divergence of your vector field?)

You don't need to know what the region V looks like (i.e., you definitely don't need to assume it is a unit cube); you just need to know its volume.